# Get values into edit form angular

Tags: angularjs

Inside main.view.html I have button Edit:
`<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="redirectEdit($index)" >Edit</md-button>` which has `redirectEdit($index)` so it takes index of current line (to have values) in main.controller.js it looks like:

```
$scope.redirectEdit = function(index){
        $scope.all[index];
        window.location = "../ang/#!/edit";
        $scope.name =$scope.all[index].name;
        $scope.surname =$scope.all[index].surname;            
        $scope.email =$scope.all[index].email;
        $scope.review =$scope.all[index].review; 
    };
```

with this method I want to redirect user to Edit form And have these specific taken entered into input fields.

`First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" >` 
I tried doing it like this but that doesn't work

Comment: Have you successfully moved to your edit page?

Comment: be sure in your edit page you have also $scope.all;

Comment: If you use ui router you need to send your object ($scope.all[index]) in params. (with $stateParams). Or you can use localStorage or service for send your object. (Preferable $stateParams if you use redirect). For redirect with ui router use $state.go('myForm'). Don't use window.location.

Comment: What you get in $scope.all[index] ? did you tried to console it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your scenario, i would suggest you to use `$emit` and `$on`.Also make a object of all fields like `$scope.formFields = {};`

```
$scope.redirectEdit = function(index){
        $scope.all[index];
        $scope.formFields = {};
        $scope.formFields.name =$scope.all[index].name;
        $scope.formFields.surname =$scope.all[index].surname;            
        $scope.formFields.email =$scope.all[index].email;
        $scope.formFields.review =$scope.all[index].review; 
        $scope.$emit('userData', {data: $scope.formFields}); //to set the value
        window.location = "../ang/#!/edit";
    };
```

And on editController.js get the data and accordingly assign values to `ng-model`

```
$rootScope.$on('userData', function (event, data) {}); // to get the value
```

I hope this helps